# .find() returns objects in debug console but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code aims to iterate x number of times, and each time insert a piece of HTML into a div.

My main HTML looks something like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Main Page Test Title</h1>
    <div class="container ">
        <div id="button_list">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The HTML I want to load during each iteration of the loop is:

```
<button class=' btn-block btn-lg'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <img class="img_class" src='test.png' height='144' width='192'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
        <h3 class="h3_class">Test Title</h3>
        <p class="p_class">Test, Test, Test keyword, Key, Word</p>
    </div>
</button>
```

The code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
        var $var = $('<div id="rbtn' + i +'">').load("button_template.html");
        $("#button_list").append($var);

        $var2 = $('#rbtn' + i);
        $var3 = $var2.find('h3');
    }
});
```

When i run this code, the buttons populate properly into the main page, and the `$var2 = $('#rbtn' + i)` selector does return an object, however the additional `$var3 = $var2.find('h3')` returns an empty object. When i run the code in google chrome debug mode, and use the console to view the value of $var2, i see the proper object. If in console mode i manually type `$var2.find('h3');` i also get the proper object. However when i do the same exact thing in code it does not work.

Comment: Even if no DOM element match to the selector, you'll still get an jQuery object with no DOM elements attach to it (i.e `$var2.length === 0`). What exactly are you expecting to be returned from `$('#btn'+i)`?

Comment: Oh, and read the documentation of [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), make sure to run this code in the callback function (with the nessacary canges made in it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trapped into a classic problem of asynchronous code. You are populating the contents of your `#rbtn`-divs by using the `$.load()` function. This function loads data from the server and inserts the contents into the `#rbtn` div as soon as the loading procedure finished.

However, loading the data is not an instant process, i.e. it finishes at a point later in time. And since Javascript code is not synchronous, the statements that you put after your call to `$.load()` get evaluated directly after the call to `$.load()` without waiting for the results. The reason that it works in your Chrome console is simply that you evaluate your statements there way ahead in time when everything is loaded already.

Thus, when you try to access the contents of the `'<div id="rbtn' + i +'">'`, they might not contain a `h3` yet, since the load operation hasn't finished yet.

The right way to do this is to postpone the `$var3 = $var2.find('h3')` operation until the `$.load()` operation has completed. To do so, you can use the third function parameter to `$.load()` which is a callback function designed just for that purpose. As the [jQuery-Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for `.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )` state, you should restructure your code to include the callback like

```
...
.load("button_template.html", function() {
  // this function will be executed as soon as the html template has been loaded and injected
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

$.load() is async function. As the code run into find("h3"), your templ doesn't load yet. You should do this in the callback function.

```
xxx.load("xxx.html", function(){
  xx.find("h3").text("xxx");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Be sure to instantiate the variables before setting them. You instantiated $var, but did not instantiate $var2 and $var3 (unless you have them set as globals somewhere not presented in the code you provided).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
        var $var = $('<div id="rbtn' + i +'">').load("button_template.html");
        $("#button_list").append($var);

        var $var2 = $('#rbtn' + i),
        $var3 = $var2.find('h3');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not the issue

Comment: If it is not THE problem, then it is still A problem. I'm getting console errors for undefined vars.

Comment: The problem is that the content of `button_template.html` load unsync, so the part of the selectors should run inside the callback function of `load()` - I didn't downvoted, but this solution sure worth it :(

Comment: I'm not disagreeing. I'm just saying that I don't even get that far - it just throws an error for the var declaration for me.

Comment: Well, this is arguable because on old browsers you can emit the ["use strict"](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp) and then you don't have to declare the variable before using it